# How do I include a whole folder in my main?

Tags: c++

I have to include a lot of `.hh` files on my main, so to put each of the `.hh` individually will take too much time. Is there a way can I add all these `".hh"` in just a few lines? I mean, instead of add `#include "blabla.hh"` a lot of time, maybe there is a way to include a folder that automatically includes all `.hh` inside it ?

Comment: Really, how many .hh files do you have?  100?  1000?  10000?  You may have too many header files when there is no more space on your hard drive or the build takes over one hour to complete.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews about 50.hh but don't worry about the hard drive. I am almost sure it can run it, since these .hh i need are not that big in space

Comment: So, how much time is "too much time".  In most of my projects, only source files that are directly modified or sources that depend on a specific header file are compiled.  I have reduced the build time by only including header files (in header files) that resolve symbols in the header file.  Also, the header file may only need to include declarations.  The source file can include the appropriate header files.  In my present project, I have over 100 source files and it is not taking "too long" to rebuild.

Comment: I also have experience, in the olden times, when complete rebuilds took a long time, so they were started at the end of the day and would be finished by the next morning.

Comment: You should try running static analysis on your files before you compile them.  This will also increase the build time.

Comment: no doubt some fancy scripting can generate a file that finds all the header files you want and prepends their names with `#include ` on each line, then you can just copy/paste it into your source file. But if you've found yourself in a situation where you truly need to `#include` 50+ header files in one file, particularly `main`, perhaps consider a re-architecture with better modularization.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, this is in general not a good idea as you're increasing the compilation time, but really it is recommended only to include the headers of classes/functions you need in a given cpp file.

So if you really need it, you could have a "include_all.hh" header file which manually includes all the necessary headers; but there isn't a from folder import * within #include

Comment: Megalithic (sp?) header files are not a good idea.  With individual header files only sources that depend on a modified header file are built.  With an include-all header file, all sources will be rebuilt because there is only one header file that many sources depend on.

Comment: Yes, never really came across where  such a thing was a necessity, and can't really think of someone having that much build time ;)

Comment: I work for a medical device company.  Our "rebuilds" pass through 2 static analysis tools before the compiler gets to the code.  This makes the builds very long duration, so as individual developers, we try not to perform rebuilds when we make changes (the rebuilds are reserved for checkins to the master branch).